# mask element on background image with transparent color overlay

Tags: html, css, background, transparency, transparent

[image: sample transparency]

That is example of what i try to achieve. Body has background image. Over the image is opacity layer. Then I got list of elements, which background supposed to be masked so that it is fully transparent.

Is it even possible with CSS ?
failed DEMO: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wL59b37L/10/)

HTML structure:

```
<div id="opacity">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="mask">
                <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#">
                    <img src="name.png" class="thumb" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="mask">
                <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="#">
                    <img src="name.png" class="thumb" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, it is. But *all* children of a transparent parent are also transparent. So you have to push the *non-transparent* elements into it with `position:relative` or `position:absolute`.

Comment: I would put the background with `z-index:1`, the frames with `z-index:0` and calculate to have the opacity on the frames as wished by a sum of background and frame. Or just see @Danko.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I know you can fake it is setting that image on the `mask` containers too adding the property

```
 background-attachment: fixed;
```

Like this:

```
.mask {
   background-image: url(http://justbeecosmetics.com/img/headImage.jpg); 
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Check The Updated **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wL59b37L/11/)**

**From W3**

> The background-attachment property specifies whether a background image is fixed with regard to the viewport or scrolls along with the containing block.

The default value is `scroll`then if you set it to `fixed`

> The background image does not scrolls with the element.

Is attached to the viewport.

Comment: There is one problem. If you make the result window very small, you can scroll. Then you see the problem. %)P

Comment: @DOCASAREL you're right I guees you can also make a container with the background not attach that to the body .... all depends of the use and behavior you want of the containers check this http://jsfiddle.net/wL59b37L/14/

Comment: Interesting way of solving this issue... Out of curiosity, is there even rational explanation for this method? In my case, it is enough, thanks Mr!

Comment: @bojar check the update ... you can also play with that property to  set the exact behavior you want

Answer (score 2):

How about using borders with rgba() values to give transparency :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wL59b37L/12/)**

*CSS :*

```
body {
    background-image: url(http://justbeecosmetics.com/img/headImage.jpg); 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

}

#opacity {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;left:0;
    width: 100%;height: 100%;
}

ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    position:relative;
}
ul li:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    left:-9999px;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-left-width: 9999px;
    border-top-width:9999px;
    border-bottom-width:9999px;
    border-right-width:20px;
    border-style:solid;
}
ul li:nth-child(2):after{
    left:0px;
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-top-width:9999px;
    border-bottom-width:9999px;
    border-right-width:9999px;
}
.mask {
    background:transparent;
    padding:50px;
}
.thumb {
    width:80px;height:80px;
}
```

Comment: +1 nice solution too ... The problem here is if you want later to add more elements you will need to recalculate everything.